# Can JWTs be exclusive to a client?

Tags: javascript, security, sails.js, jwt

I am new to the concept of authentication and JWTs. I modified my Sails app to generate JWTs with the help of [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). I sign the JWTs like this: `jwt.sign(payload, secret, { expiresInMinutes: 120 });`

1. Doesn't this mean a client having access to the token can access the protected resources?
2. How should the payload be used? Should I save the user-agent string in the payload and verify it on the client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anyone in possession of the token can call your API. That's why everything should go over SSL, and expiration should be in line with the sensitivity of what it is doing.

The JWT will typically be sent on the `Authorization` header:

`Authorization: Bearer {your token here}`

BTW, you can test contents/signatures here: http://jwt.io